# Not able to change the name of a contact from a vf page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, salesforce-classic

**VF Code**

```
<apex:page controller="Buffer">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
             <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveMethod}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!c}" var="t">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!t.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code**

```
public class Buffer 
{
    public List<Contact> c {get;set;}
    public String ids{set;get;}
    
    public Buffer()
    {
        ids=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        c = new List<Contact>([select Name from Contact where id=:ids]);
    }
    
     public PageReference SaveMethod()
    {
        update c;
        return new PageReference('/'+ids);
    }    
}
```

[image]

I am trying to change the name of the contact and click Save, but the name of the contact remains the same and doesn't get changed.

Could anyone please let me know what exact change can be done to the code so that I can edit the name of the contact and save it successfully from the vf page.

Comment: P.S. `c = new List<Contact>([select Name from Contact where id=:ids]);` is redundant, as the result of a query is already a List. `c = [select Name from Contact where id=:ids];` works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the Name field; it is a compound field that uses FirstName, MiddleName (if enabled), Last Name, and Suffix. You need to edit the individual fields, instead.

```
<apex:column headerValue="First Name">
  <apex:inputField value="{!t.FirstName}" />
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
  <apex:inputField value="{!t.LastName}" />
</apex:column>
```

Also, note that you need to query a field in order to use it:

```
c = [select FirstName,LastName from Contact where id=:ids];
```

Comment: I was going to say, even if he could edit the Name field, wouldn't he have to use inputField instead of inputText? Or does that component also work to edit directly sObject fields?

Comment: @joacoiudica I didn't notice that, but ultimately, it doesn't matter. `apex:inputText` works just as well as `apex:inputField` if you know the field is a text field, except the former does not respect field level security (so, if they'd used the latter, the field would have been read only, which should have been a clue).

Comment: @joacoiudica actually, in retrospect, they may have tried to use `apex:inputField` first, and it wasn't showing an input element, so they then tried `apex:inputText`. I could imagine a younger me doing that until I realized what's wrong. In fact, I probably did do that at least once while I was learning Visualforce.

Comment: @sfdcfox I did try the snippet of code provided by you, but I am getting error as below:

**SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.FirstName**

Comment: @AliBaba Yes, I just realized you named the var `t`. I've edited this answer to reflect that. Also, you need to add those fields to the query in order to use them.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks a lot, I am new to visualforce, having got support from pros like you during learning phase is amazing, got to learn something new today!!
Have a nice day!